# How to select between different vcpkg libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vcpkg

I have installed both `tesseract:x64-windows` and `tesseract:x64-windows-static` via vcpkg. In my Visual Studio project, I can `#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>` and it will automagically compile but I have no idea whether the static or dynamic version of the library is being linked and I also have no idea how to switch between them. What setting lets me see / change that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For VS integration you could try out PR https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/4361 or just set the MSBuild property `VcpkgTriplet` according to:
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/buildsystems/msbuild-integration.md

Comment: 404 error on that integration.md link

Comment: yeah they moved the docs in an overhaul. Fixed the link